# Is it possible to integrate R code into a shell script without calling an R script?

Tags: r, shell

I have a shell script that calls an R script and they work just fine. However, I'm trying to make this more portable and reduce the number of files needed. Is it possible to push the code from my R script into the shell script?

It looks like

```
    #!/usr/bin/bash
    #Assorted shell code
    Rscript R_script.r arg1 arg2
    #Additional shell code
```

I want to see something like

```
    #!/usr/bin/bash
    #Assorted shell code
    R
    #Assorted R code
    q() #To return to shell
```

So far, I haven't found anything online that suggests this can be done, but I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Linux (which I assume as you are using bash) you can feed your R code to [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) like this

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "Hello"
echo 'x <- 2
print(x)' | r
echo "Done"
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems more or less like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Oops, entered that too early.

Two questions:

Can I just wrap my entire R script in that echo and pipe it to r like that? That'd be real handy.

For anyone else that looks at this, I'm getting a "Fatal error: you must specify '--save', '--no-save' or '--vanilla' with this set up after installing littler. I haven't yet resolved it, so the second question is "any tips to fix that?"

Comment: What operating system are you using? This sounds as if R is being called instead of r. Some operating systems do not differentiate, Linux does.

Comment: Dirk gives a hint on his littler page on what might help on Os X. And yes, I think you could pipe your whole script like this, if it does not contain the type of quote you use to quote it.

Comment: Ubuntu16.04. What's the difference between R and r? That may be my issue.

Comment: R is the normal way to start the R interpreter. r is a binary that comes with the littler package that is optimised for scripting.

Comment: On Ubuntu, you should install r-cran-littler to get `/usr/bin/r`.

Comment: Oh, I get it. I just need to add it to my path, then. Thanks!